# Extract Data from Returned JSON String (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, json, winforms, google-maps

I am trying to get the address using the postcode using the Google Mapping API. So far I can get the JSON data back from the response and store it in a 'var'.

However I can't extract the fields such as street, town and county -> ideally into a separate string variable for each.

Here is my code so far.

```
string postcode = Convert.ToString(tbPostcode.Text);

string searchCode = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + postcode + "&sensor=false";
var result = "";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchCode);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write("");
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Adam

Comment: If you don't mind using a third party library, I find `JSON.NET` to be a good library for parsing JSON data http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: Would you think getting the data back in XML would be easier?

Comment: Not necessarily. The JSON returned isn't particularly difficult to parse, especially with `JSON.NET` or the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class astander mentioned. Even with XML, you'll have to parse the data so it's more a case of what format you're happy to work with.

Comment: You should also take a look at the terms of use of Google MAps API since using the service out of the display of a map control might put you in an unauthorized use of the service depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like

[How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Which makes use of [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Serializes objects to the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and
>   deserializes JSON data to objects.

This should help you to create tyhe C# classes you need

[json2csharp : generate c# classes from json](http://json2csharp.com/)